# double hsts header for kubernetes nginx

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

app1: hsts enabled at backend

app2: hsts not enabled

I am trying to enable hsts for specific domain at nginx-ingress(https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/basic-configuration/)

however, I have one application in that cluster already have hsts enabled while the another not.
So, if i add it at the config map it will take effect for both the service which will cause double hsts header for app 1.

I am currently enabling the hsts for all like as below:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
   name: nginx-config-map
   namespace: default
data:
   http2: "true"
   ssl-redirect: "true"
   ssl-protocols: TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
   ssl-prefer-server-ciphers: "true"
   ssl-ciphers: #########
   set-real-ip-from: 0.0.0.0/0
   real-ip-header: X-Forwarded-For
   # hsts enabled 
   server-snippets: 'add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;"'
```

not sure if I am working in the correct track to resolve the hsts, looking forward to hearing from others. :)

*updates*

i came across where I am able to perform an if else.. just wondering if there is anyway that i can differentiate by my virtual server?

https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/3f0740d182a9f46cfc83ef085d9721cb102c97b9/examples/customization/nginx-config.yaml#L43

Comment: Have you tried using `nginx.org/server-snippets` ingress annotation to enable hsts only for app2 and not globally?

Comment: @HelloWorld i am currently using the nginx.org/server-snippets at the last line of my configmap. or i interpreted differently?

Comment: this is not what I meant. I meant annotation in ingress object associated with app2. Not global configuration of nginx ingress controller

Comment: Hmm, but based on the documentation there is only 1 ingress object that is associate with multiple apps. https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/deployments/deployment/nginx-ingress.yaml

Comment: Please read [this docs about ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) to understand ingress concepts.